# How to graph data interval versus price in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm trying to graph a data interval versus price. Basically, I'm looking for a Scatter Plot - Line with Markers, where the markers are at the Start and End Dates, with a horizontal line between them indicating Price.

Basically I'm trying to graph the price of a rental property versus the date, since the property rents at different prices in summer compared to winter. Each "rental" would be a different horizontal line beginning at the start date and ending at the end date, with a height equivalent to the price per night. Looking at how many lines and their height I could get an idea of how to play with price.

Edit:" I included an image here but I had to remove it to attach the two pictures below of how I solved it."

Any suggestions?

Update - 2017.06.28

Thanks for the answer, @Bandersnatch. I ended up seeing it after arriving at a solution of my own by chance. My solution wasn't all that elegant but it is accurate. Pics below:

- Thats how the graph I was looking for came out. Each color represents a different year, and each segment a different "stay". Each line is actually a bunch of dots, so in that sense it isn't very elegant. But it does work exactly how I wanted it to.

Graph of end result:

[image: Graph of end result]

- Thats the data. I input columns D, E and F; and it calculates G and H. Then I have to populate columns L on by hand manually. There is a column for each year (L-P) and a row for every day of the year. I just set all the dates as 1900 (so excel dates number 1-366) so I could graph multiple years in a same graph, with each year being a different series. I'm sure there is a better way, but all in all it takes me less time to do it like that then to solve it "the right way".

Data for graph above:

[image: Data for graph above]

I think I'm going to just leave it like this for now, unless anyone has any suggestions on how to autofill columns L onwards from columns D, E and H. I guess some way to make the lines an actual segment instead of discrete points would be nice, but I can't complain.

I'm surprised I haven't seen anything else similar to this. The information is super useful in my situation, so I was expecting a quick Google search to show how someone else did it.

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow. Please post sample data with desired output (even a drawing is fine) to help us understanding your issue.

Comment: @mvsainz, if you'd like to show pictures in a question (without an external link) you can do so as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: Also, if you found this answer helpful, please award points as explained [here](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Bandersnatch, as far as I'm aware, I can't post images since I don't have enough reputation points yet. I read the link but it just seemed to confirm that.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Glad you got this solved.  The site's Q&A format relies on questions being just questions and answers being solutions to them.  Including an answer within the question makes the question unclear, and others can't search for the answer.  Instead, please post the answer portion as an answer post (read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.  Since you want individual horizontal lines (some of which can overlap), you need to have a separate data series for each horizontal bar. I've included 10 or so in this table.

[image]

Graph the data with a scatter graph as before, coloring the line of each series red.  Here is what this data gave:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! I saw this after arriving at a solution of my own. It's detailed above in case you're curious.

Regarding your excel data, the idea is interesting, but in practice that graph would be extremely large with the vast majority of cells empty. The solution I arrived at ended up being pretty much two different tables, and pretty intelligible. I'm really happy with the insight it gave me. I can only wonder if I could make the 2nd table autopopulate from the first, or make the discrete points of the graph lines, but I doubt it's worth any extra effort since it works fine as is.